# Tikz: Using self intersection of knots library in an align environment throws error

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, tikz-knots

Correct me if it's bad style but I used `align` to horizontally order multiple `tikzpicture`'s and discovered the following.
Take the standard example for self intersections from the [manual](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/knots_doc.pdf) for the knots package and put it inside an `align` environment. If `consider self intersections` is enabled this throws an error, otherwise it works fine.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,knots}

\begin{document}        
\begin{align}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true]
      \strand (0, 0)  .. controls  +(3, 1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
    \end{knot}
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And the error message:

```
ERROR: Argument of \__fp_parse_expand:w has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \end{align}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Is there a way to get self intersections to work in `align` or should I better look for alternative ways to order the pictures?

Comment: `align` is for equations. What precisely do you want to achieve? You could use, say, a tabular to align them horizontally.

Comment: Do you need equation numbering for them, or are you just looking to get multiple such diagrams next to each other?

Comment: If the latter, you could just have multiple `knot` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, and use e.g. `\begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true,xshift=3cm]` to move some knots to the right.

Comment: Yes I'll need equation numbers. I'm using knot diagrams which represent mathematical equations, so ideally I would like to work with these tikz pictures in the same way as with usual formulas.

Comment: Just discovered that putting the above tikzpicture inside brackets { } solves the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to center objects in an equation is to use `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}        
\begin{align}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.78);
    \begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true]
      \strand (0, 0)  .. controls  +(3, 1) and +(-3,1) .. (1,0);
    \end{knot}
 \end{tikzpicture}}}&=7
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why I added the bounding box manually is that Ti*k*Z overestimates the bounding box of Bézier curves.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the `knots` library relating to comparing `fp`s which only came to light when the knot environment was contained in some sort of alignment environment.  I've now fixed that on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) and it will make its way to CTAN in due course.