# Tikz knots in tabular consider self intersections throws error: You can't use \unskip after \the. <argument> \unskip

Tags: tables, tikz-knots

I want to draw a Knot, using the tikzlibary knots, inside a tabular. When I specify consider self intersections inside the knot environment I get an error:

```
You can't use `\unskip' after \the. <argument> \unskip
```

Without the consider self intersection it works flawlessly. I am using pdfLaTeX in TeXworks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{knot}[
        draft mode=crossings,
        consider self intersections,]
            \strand[red,ultra thick, xscale=.2, yscale=.2]   (+-5.1498,+-0.3069)
              .. controls (+-4.6351,+2.6312) and (+-2.9828,+5.3368) .. (+0.0000,+5.3368)
              .. controls (+2.9828,+5.3368) and (+4.6351,+2.6312) .. (+5.1498,+-0.3069)
              .. controls (+5.4153,+-1.8225) and (+5.0220,+-3.2691) .. (+3.6412,+-3.9480)
              .. controls (+1.7709,+-4.8675) and (+-0.8477,+-4.5300) .. (+-1.5119,+-2.5546)
              .. controls (+-2.1181,+-0.7515) and (+1.1716,+-0.1591) .. (+1.4680,+1.3004)
              .. controls (+1.8076,+2.9727) and (+-3.5678,+6.6995) .. (+0.0470,+6.6995)
              .. controls (+3.6619,+6.6995) and (+-1.7955,+2.9828) .. (+-1.4680,+1.3004)
              .. controls (+-1.1834,+-0.1614) and (+2.1181,+-0.7515) .. (+1.5119,+-2.5546)
              .. controls (+0.8477,+-4.5300) and (+-1.7709,+-4.8675) .. (+-3.6412,+-3.9480)
              .. controls (+-5.0220,+-3.2691) and (+-5.4153,+-1.8225) .. (+-5.1498,+-0.3069)
              -- cycle;
        \end{knot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding consoleprintout, thanks for helping:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./TikzError.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.
tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-
lists.tex))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.d
ef)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.t
ex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.te
x
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered
.code.tex))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex
.def
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common
-pdf.def)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpat
h.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotoco
l.code.tex)) (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.t
ex (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex

(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.t
ex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.cod
e.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
ic.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.tri
gonometric.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.ran
dom.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.com
parison.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
e.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rou
nd.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.mis
c.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.int
egerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.te
x)) (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)

(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.
code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathcon
struct.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusa
ge.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.
code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphic
state.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransfo
rmations.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.c
ode.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects
.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathpro
cessing.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.
code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.c
ode.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.c
ode.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexterna
l.code.tex))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.
code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspa
rency.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepattern
s.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.cod
e.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.c
ode.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.cod
e.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-0-65.sty)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-1-18.sty))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.te
x)) (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.c
ode.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryploth
andlers.code.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.c
ode.tex)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librar
ies/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibraryknots.code.te
x (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/spath3.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
) (d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-1
0-01.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generi
c.tex))))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librar
ies/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryinter
sections.code.tex
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.c
ode.tex)))
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibraryspath3.code.t
ex)) (./TikzError.aux)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(d:/Programme/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! You can't use `\unskip' after \the.
<argument> \unskip 
                   
l.23        \end{knot}
                 
?
```

Comment: Missed this first time round.  Does the `tabular` environment matter here? Does removing it also remove the error?

Comment: Turns out this is the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514566/tikz-using-self-intersection-of-knots-library-in-an-align-environment-throws-er?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the `knots` library relating to comparing `fp`s which only came to light when the knot environment was contained in some sort of alignment environment.  I've now fixed that on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) and it will make its way to CTAN in due course.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `consider self intersections=no splits` option. Given the output, you may want to reconsider the coordinates somewhat, or add `ignore endpoint intersections=false` and adjust the `clip radius`.

[image]

Above: Added `consider self intersections=no splits`

Below: Also added `ignore endpoint intersections=false` and `clip radius=5pt`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{knot}[
        draft mode=crossings,
        consider self intersections=no splits,
        ignore endpoint intersections=false,
        clip radius=5pt]
            \strand[red,ultra thick, xscale=.2, yscale=.2]   (+-5.1498,+-0.3069)
              .. controls (+-4.6351,+2.6312) and (+-2.9828,+5.3368) .. (+0.0000,+5.3368)
              .. controls (+2.9828,+5.3368) and (+4.6351,+2.6312) .. (+5.1498,+-0.3069)
              .. controls (+5.4153,+-1.8225) and (+5.0220,+-3.2691) .. (+3.6412,+-3.9480)
              .. controls (+1.7709,+-4.8675) and (+-0.8477,+-4.5300) .. (+-1.5119,+-2.5546)
              .. controls (+-2.1181,+-0.7515) and (+1.1716,+-0.1591) .. (+1.4680,+1.3004)
              .. controls (+1.8076,+2.9727) and (+-3.5678,+6.6995) .. (+0.0470,+6.6995)
              .. controls (+3.6619,+6.6995) and (+-1.7955,+2.9828) .. (+-1.4680,+1.3004)
              .. controls (+-1.1834,+-0.1614) and (+2.1181,+-0.7515) .. (+1.5119,+-2.5546)
              .. controls (+0.8477,+-4.5300) and (+-1.7709,+-4.8675) .. (+-3.6412,+-3.9480)
              .. controls (+-5.0220,+-3.2691) and (+-5.4153,+-1.8225) .. (+-5.1498,+-0.3069)
              -- cycle;
        \end{knot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```